# TensorFlow: Access Contents of a Variable By Name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following situation:

I have already built, trained and saved my net.  Now, I am trying to restore the net and visualize the weight matrices.

I know all the names for the variables, but I don't have a python marker assigned to the variable to pass to the session for evaluation.  How do I retrieve the data in the variable?

Here is my code situation:

```
dataset_params = nn_params.mnist_dataset_params
design = nn_designs.mnist_net_A_design
## Build Housing Object
mnist_nn = nn_class.CNN(**dataset_params)
mnist_nn.build_net(design['design'])
mnist_nn.__setattr__('saved_path',saved_model)
mnist_nn_epoch_file = saved_model+'_epochs_completed.txt'
mnist_nn.__setattr__('epoch_file',mnist_nn_epoch_file)


# evaluate weight variables
session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
saver.restore(session,saved_model)




session.close()
```

What should I pass to session in order to pull out the weights? (An example weight name is: 'conv_w_1')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this is using the [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#get_collection) lookup method to get the desired variable:

```
weight_var = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, "conv_w_1")[0]

weight_var_value = session.run(weight_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get the result by using function tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name:

```
    valua_of_conv_w_1 = session.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("conv_w_1:0"))
```